# How to get VLOOKUP count and sum up the results from lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have tried these to formulas:

=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(B3;Sakthi!H3:J1048576;2;FALSE))

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B3;Sakthi!$H$3:$J$1048576;2;);"")

both of them should have given me the result of 42 but are only giving me the result from the first match found for the lookup value.

i will like it to sum all the matches for "TMS1535" and then return the sum of those.

Please help me where i am making the mistake.

thanks in advance.
susanne.

Comment: For us to replicate what you are after, could you make this a question with a [mcve], meaning please add mockup sample data in markdown format for us to work with.

Answer (score 1):

=SUMIF(Sakthi!$H$2:$H$1048576;B3;Sakthi!$I$2:$I$1048576)

this one fixed it for me.